# Natural Breaks (Jenks) classes as a new column values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, classification

I have .shp layer with column `Length`

In Layer Properties it's possible to display Layer with natural breaks (Jenks) classification.

It's shown below:
[image]

Based on that classification I'd like to create new column which store Natural Breaks (Jenks) classes for example if some object displays as 1 I want 1 in created column etc.

Obviously I could write statement in field calculator (after classification in Layer Properties) like (simply version):

```
if Length < first_class_high_value then 1 etc.
```

But I'd like to put creating new field in Model in order to using with many Layers, so I wouldn't know threshold value for each class.

Any idea how solve that problem?

Comment: You'll need to choose between implementing  the natural breaks algorithm in Python or descibing the classes to extract ranges.

Comment: I've tried implementing algorithm in python, but it didn't work. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Not without several hours of donated labor. If, however, you alter the question to contain your code and debug output, with test data against which to validate the algorithm, then maybe someone here can help.

Comment: I've found that https://gist.github.com/drewda/1299198 but don't know how use it in my case :/